# Kotlin: Extension function to widen list type param (or any covariant type param)

Tags: kotlin, generics, extension-methods, type-level-computation

I need an extension function to widen the type of covariant container like a List.

So imagine the following scenario:

```kotlin
val listOfInts = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)

val listOfNumbers = listOfInts.widen<Number>() //would be of type List<Number>
```

I just can't manage to achieve that.

I could write the following:

```kotlin
fun <U:Any,T:U> List<T>.widen():List<U> = this
```

But then, it needs to be invoked like:

```kotlin
listOfInts.widen<Number,_>()
```

YEAH! I know, it's just 2 extra characters, but they ruin the ergonomics of the library I'm writing

Help, please!

Comment: Why do you need this?  You can just use `listOfInts` anywhere you'd use a `List<Number>`, or store it to a variable of that type.

Comment: `fun <T> List<T>.widen() = this` should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was noodling on ways to accomplish this, reading up on generics, and the documentation itself has a function for this. It may be overkill with the type checking and nulling, but it is safer.

More Strict:

```
fun <T> List<T>.widen(): List<T> = this
```

Less Strict: [From Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#unchecked-casts)

```
inline fun <reified T> List<*>.asListOfType(): List<T>? =
    if (all { it is T })
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        this as List<T> else
        null
```

Comment: Just came up with such KISS solution... :facepalm: I'm actually using it with something which cannot be verified like a list

Comment: Do you need this for non-list type items?

Comment: What is unsafe about the first way? It looks completely safe to me. What's an example of something that would fail with it? The second way has the problem of returning a nullable and the compiler will permit you to call it with types that are not supertypes of the input List's type (which may be good or bad depending on what this is used for). The second way isn't strictly for widening, and could be used for narrowing as well.

Comment: Safe wasn't the correct word, in retrospect. I was more focused on the explicit checking. Like you pointed out, the 2nd instance would work either direction, Strict may have been better word choice.